# Returning Levenshtein Distance result as percentage?

Tags: php

How to return the Levenshtein Distance as percentage ?

Example :

```
$s1 = abc;
$s2 = ab;
$lev = levenshtein($s1,$s2);
```

The `$lev` variable will return the distance value which is 1. How do I make the distance value to percentage ? Like the `$s1` and `$s2` has 80% similarity..

Comment: How do you arrive at 80%?

Comment: `(max(strlen($s1), strlen($s2)) - $lev) / max(strlen($s1), strlen($s2)) * 100`

Comment: Divide Levenstein distance by `max(strlen($s1), strlen($s2))`, maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`abc` and `ab` are similar to ~66%.

Try this:

```
function _levenshtein($str1, $str2) {
    return (1 - levenshtein($str1, $str2)/max(strlen($str1), strlen($str2)))*100;
}

echo _levenshtein('abc', 'ab'); //66.66
```